# Jetpack compose AndroidView coming over the top bar

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm using jetpack compose with kotlin. When I use an AndroidView its coming over the top bar as you see on the SS. What is the reason of this?

[image: Screenshot of the error]

Comment: Hi, Can you add the code for the above layout?

Comment: I'm also experiencing this. It happens when doing something like

```AndroidView(factory = ..., update = ..., modifier = Modifier.statusBarsPadding())
```